# Channel.channelInterestChanged in Netty

Tags: java, netty

I am working with Netty Channels and when sending lots of data across the channel , I notice that the `Channel.channelInterestChanged` event gets fired, which immediately results in `Channel.isWritable()` to return false.(  there is another thread doing a `Channel.write()` and this thread fails immediately ). My question is : why is the Channel's interests getting changed ? or rather who is changing it ? Nothing in code that I wrote ( server or client ) changes the interests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It gets changed because you write more data to the Channel then it can transmit in a given time. Netty queues the data for you until some treshold is hit, once it is hit Channel.isWritable() will return false.

You have to adjust the writeBufferHighWaterMark and writeBufferLowWaterMark if you want to change how many bytes are allowed to get queued/buffered before Channel.isWritable() returns false.

```
ServerBootstrap sb = ....
sb.setOption("writeBufferHighWaterMark", ..);
sb.setOption("writeBufferLowWaterMark", ..);
```

Anyway you should make sure that your code that calls Channel.write(...) does check Channel.isWritable() and only write to if it returns true. The problem you have are often seen in slow networks.

[1] http://netty.io/docs/stable/api/org/jboss/netty/channel/socket/nio/NioChannelConfig.html

Comment: if channel is not writable what should we do ?

Comment: Stop writing and continue once it is writable again

Comment: is there a way to detect window frame size changes on remote using netty ? if there is, can we do anything at application level to react this ?

Comment: Nope there is not... Only if its part of the protocol like for example in http2